# How do I use a part of the matched text in regex for Sublime Text, in the replacement?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

If I have

```
width: 12px 0;
width: 24px 0;
```

how can I use regex to replace it with

```
width: 12px 0px;
width: 24px 0px;
```

While keeping the first number intact?

I am using Sublime Text that uses Python PCRE for regex. I tried searching Google and Bing and reading the Sublime Text documentation and I couldn't find anything helpful. Using `:[0-9]*px 0;` and `:${m}px 0px;` doesn't work.

Comment: Did that work out?

Comment: I'm busy doing lots of personal projects at the moment that's taking weeks to complete. I'll try out your answer on wednesday.

Comment: Your answer works. I've given you the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
(:\h*\d+px\h+\d+);
```

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `:\h*\d+px` Match `:` optional spaces and 1+ digits followed by `px`
  - `\h+\d+` Match 1+ spaces and 1+ digits
- `)`; Close group and match `;`

And replace with the first group followed by `px;` like  `$1px;`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u14Y3t/1)

[image]

---

Without using a capture group, this could be another option using `\K` to forget what is matched so far, and replace with `px;`

```
:\h*\d+px\h+\d+\K;
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gn12DK/1)

Comment: If OP's data is as mentioned (but at risk of oversimplification) you could try: `(\d+);` replaced with `$1px;`, though not worth an answer =). Nice 1

Comment: I never used `\h` and `\K`. Does `\h` have different meanings on different regex implementations?

Comment: @qräbnö `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace character and `\K` resets the current match buffer. See these pages for the different engines that support them. http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#other and http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#whitespace

Comment: Thx. `\h` can also mean hexadecimal digit shorthand on other engines.